# Group By Query with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by, entity-framework-6

In my application I have **Movements** associated with a **category**. 
I want a list of the most frequent **category**.

My objects are:

**Category**: **catId**, catName 

**Movement**: Movid, movDate, movMount, **catId**

I think it would have to raise it with a "Group By" query (grouping by catId and getting those more)
(Im using Entity Framework 6 in c#)

From already thank you very much!

Comment: it sounds like you know what you need.  What problem did you have when you tried to use `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this help:

```
var query = dbContext.Category.Select(u => new 
{ 
    Cat = u, 
    MovementCount = u.Movement.Count() 
})
.ToList()
.OrderByDescending(u => u.MovementCount)
.Select(u => u.Cat)
.ToList();
```

Comment: worked perfectly! I did not realize one thing: I did not know that EF generates an attribute "Movement" on "Category" class, when the FK (of database) goes from Movement to Category

Answer (score 3):

IMPORTANT: Entity Framework 7 (now renamed to Entity Framework Core 1.0) does not yet support GroupBy() for translation to GROUP BY in generated SQL. Any grouping logic will run on the client side, which could cause a lot of data to be loaded.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-rc2

Comment: Still doesn't btw :-(

Answer (score 2):

group the movements by category and select catid and count.
join this result with category to get the name and then descending sort the results on count.

```
var groupedCategories = context.Movements.GroupBy(m=>m.catId).Select(g=>new {CatId = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});    
var frequentCategories = groupedCategories.Join(context.Categories, g => g.CatId, c => c.catId, (g,c) => new { catId = c.catId, catName = c.catName, count = g.Count }).OrderByDescending(r => r.Count);

foreach (var category in frequentCategories)
{
 // category.catId, category.catName and category.Count
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raja!!, it helps me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use `navigation property` on `category` simply, you have a navigation property on category contains all related `Movement`, i call it `Movements` in following query. you can write your query like this, with minimum of connection with `DB`.

```
class Cat
{
     public Guid catId { get; set; }
     public string catName { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Movement> Movements { get; set; }
     public int MovementsCount { get { return Movements.Count(); } }
}

var Categories = category.Select(u => new Cat() 
{
    u.catId, 
    u.catName,     
    Movements = u.Movements.AsEnumerable()
}).ToList();

var CategoriesIncludeCount = Categories.OrderBy(u => u.MovementsCount).ToList();
```

Comment: Thnks Amir!, i resolve the problem in a "Manager" class which have the ranking method. but it's interesting what you raise. Post this inquiry within the category class could help a lot! would combine the above solution with which you offer.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you want exactly, but `tsql` is generated by my linq query is more lightweight than the post you have checked as answer. in that query you need an extra `group by`, and `.Count()` in `data base` side, but in my query you have not `group by` and you get `Count` from result set have been already fetched and do this in memory. and this, increase your performance

Comment: I have the following data structure: 

Category: catId (pk), catNombre 
Movement: Movid (Pk), movDescription, catId, movQuantity 

I need a list of the categories that are more associated movements. 

Try your solution, but I need to return a list of "Category" and not "Cat". 
Moreover, as I relate the categories with the movements? 

Movements <Movement> public IEnumerable {get; September; } 
. 
. 
. 
U.Movements.AsEnumerable Movements = () 
(I need to get them from the DB) 

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem!

I used the proposal by "Raja" solution (Thanks a lot!).

This return a collection composed of "Category" and "Count". I Change it a bit to return a list of Categories.

```
var groupedCategories = model.Movement.GroupBy(m => m.catId).Select(
                                g => new {catId= g.Key, Count = g.Count() }); 

var freqCategories= groupedCategories.Join(model.Category, 
                                              g => g.catId, 
                                              c => c.catId, 
                                              (g, c) => new {category = c, count = g.Count}).OrderByDescending(ca => ca.count).Select(fc => fc.category).ToList ();
```